# why i get null pointer exception?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

i have posted my coding below, i want to enter the date and store it into the database throught j s p. when i execute i get null pointer exception. what change must be done? can anyone help?

my stack trace is

Stacktrace:

```
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

root cause

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1235)
java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:335)
org.apache.jsp.sample_005fvalidate_jsp._jspService(sample_005fvalidate_jsp.java:101)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.text.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>ALLOCATION</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000">


<%
    Connection con = null;

    String StaffName = request.getParameter("StaffName");
    String hourId = request.getParameter("hourId");
    if(hourId==null)
    hourId="";
    String day = request.getParameter("day");
   if (day==null)
    day="";
    String date = request.getParameter("date");
  SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");here
  java.util.Date dateStr = formatter.parse(date); // (this is the line that cannot be proccessed)
   java.sql.Date dateDB = new java.sql.Date(dateStr.getTime());
   if (date==null)
      date="";

    try {
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          con =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/StaffAllocation","root","success") ;

       // PreparedStatement stat = con.PrepareStatement();
        String updateString ="INSERT INTO tblstaffallocation     (StaffName,hourId,daysId,date) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";   
       //'"+StaffName+"','"+hour+"','"+day+"','"+date+"')
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(updateString);


        preparedStatement.setString(1, StaffName);
       preparedStatement.setInt(2, 0);
       preparedStatement.setInt(3, 0);
       preparedStatement.setDate(4,dateDB);
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: date must be null in request. Try debugging and find out the value

Comment: @ gv an @ nos what change should i do?

Comment: How are you sending the parameter "date" to the jsp you've posted in your question? Could you please provide that code?

Comment: @user2951465 make sure you have given "date" name at the front end HTML code...

Answer (score 1):

```
String date = request.getParameter("date");
```

The above line has null value. There is no "date" parameter in your request. Please check out. Check out the case of the parameter "date" in your request

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the date is passed in request. Or else put a null check before the parse statement

```
java.util.Date dateStr;
java.sql.Date dateDB;

if(date!=null){
   dateStr = formatter.parse(date); 
   dateDB = new java.sql.Date(dateStr.getTime());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
     java.util.Date dateStr=null;
     java.sql.Date dateDB=null;
     if (date!=null){
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        dateStr = formatter.parse(date);
        dateDB = new java.sql.Date(dateStr.getTime());
      }else{
          date="";
      }
```